# How does number of component trees (or number of estimators) in a Random Forest Classifier in sklearn affect its accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Does the accuracy necessarily increase when we increase the number of estimators in the Random Forest Classifier?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

Decission trees tend to overfit on the training data (they have large variance on out of sample data). Random forests were designed to overcome this difficulty by creating an ensemble of independent decision trees, which all have large individual variances, but when the voting process takes place, they tend to perform better on unseen data.

It is impossible to generalize the relationship between accuracy and `n_estimators` given the info you gave us, but you can expect it to be positive and increasing at marginally decreasing rates. That is, the more trees the better, but at some point the effect of adding more trees will become negligible.

You can try using `GridSearchCV` with `param_grid={'n_estimators':range(1, 101)}` to see the effect of adding more estimators to a random forest.

Finally, you should probably ask this kind of question on [this forum](https://datascience.stackexchange.com). Take a look at @desertnaut's comment on your post.